# AS3 Embed Code Error

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    public class main extends Sprite {

        [Embed(source="file.swf")]
        public static const MY_FILE:Class;

        public function main() {

            var mySprite:Sprite = new MY_FILE() as Sprite;
            trace("done " + MY_FILE);
            addChild(mySprite);
        }

    }
}
```

am getting this error.

```
done [class main_MY_FILE]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Filters()
```

Does anyone know what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your embedded swf. Your Script seems fine.

Comment: Yes, I have made another swf in CS4, now its working. So what is the issue with that?

Comment: Well, unless you provide a link to the swf, or a piece of the underlying code, we'll never know ;)

Comment: hhahaa, :) I heard the AVM1 and AVM2, if that is the case how can i solve?

Comment: If it's an AVM1 movie you cannot embed it.  You have to use a loader to do it.  Also, it cannot be moved anywhere in the display list (with addChild()).  It has to stay in the loader.content.

Comment: I tried the same code to load the jpg file, but it showing error? what could be the reason